# jQueryUI not working after adding duration parameter

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When added the second parameter for duration the code doesn't work. It works fine without the duration parameter.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".icon").click(function(){
    $(".menu").toggleClass("toggle-menu", 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Because the second parameter for `toggleClass` isn't a duration, it's *"A Boolean (not just truthy/falsy) value to determine whether the class should be added or removed."*

Comment: this is the demo from Jqueryui.com  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#button" ).on( "click", function() {
      $( "#effect" ).toggleClass( "newClass", 1000 );
    });
  } );
  </script>

Comment: Can any one answer this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with an example solution https://jsfiddle.net/y6rm0pfc/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".icon").click(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(".menu").toggleClass("toggle-menu");
    }, 1000)

  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.toggle-menu{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" class="icon" >
Submit
</button>

<div class="menu">

</div>
```

**toggleClass** takes only one parameter, so I have used setTimeout and then inside that I have used toggleClass

Comment: The transition effect doesnt work thats why I was using JqueryUI

Comment: Here you go with transition effect https://jsfiddle.net/y6rm0pfc/1/ . Transition is purely on CSS.